# java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection in managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I trying to debug managed bean with JSF page based on this [tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html)

This is the code of the JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" var="item">
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" />
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                    </h:form>

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the managed bean:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

// source http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html
@Named("SessionsController")
@ViewScoped
public class Sessions implements Serializable {

    /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    // Data.
    private List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList;
    private int totalRows;
    // Paging.
    private int firstRow;
    private int rowsPerPage;
    private int totalPages;
    private int pageRange;
    private Integer[] pages;
    private int currentPage;
    // Sorting.
    private String sortField;
    private boolean sortAscending;

    /* Constructor */
    public Sessions() {
        /* Set default properties */
        rowsPerPage = 10; // Default rows per page (max amount of rows to be displayed at once).
        pageRange = 10; // Default page range (max amount of page links to be displayed at once).
        sortField = "ASESSIONID"; // Default sort field.
        sortAscending = true; // Default sort direction.
    }

    private static class ActiveSessionObj {

        /* Oracle table structure
        CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
        ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
        USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
        ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITY CLOB
        )
         */
        private String aSessionID;
        private String userID;
        private Date activityStart;
        private Date activityEnd;
        private String activity;

        public ActiveSessionObj(String aSessionID, String userID, Date activityStart, Date activityEnd, String activity) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
            this.userID = userID;
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public String getaSessionID() {
            return aSessionID;
        }

        public void setaSessionID(String aSessionID) {
            this.aSessionID = aSessionID;
        }

        public String getactivity() {
            return activity;
        }

        public void setactivity(String activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public Date getactivityEnd() {
            return activityEnd;
        }

        public void setactivityEnd(Date activityEnd) {
            this.activityEnd = activityEnd;
        }

        public Date getactivityStart() {
            return activityStart;
        }

        public void setactivityStart(Date activityStart) {
            this.activityStart = activityStart;
        }

        public String getuserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public void setuserID(String userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        private ActiveSessionObj() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    // Paging actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void pageFirst() {
        page(0);
    }

    public void pageNext() {
        page(firstRow + rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pagePrevious() {
        page(firstRow - rowsPerPage);
    }

    public void pageLast() {
        page(totalRows - ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? totalRows % rowsPerPage : rowsPerPage));
    }

    public void page(ActionEvent event) {
        page(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * rowsPerPage);
    }

    private void page(int firstRow) {
        this.firstRow = firstRow;
        loadDataList(); // Load requested page.
    }

    // Sorting actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void sort(ActionEvent event) {
        String sortFieldAttribute = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("sortField");

        // If the same field is sorted, then reverse order, else sort the new field ascending.
        if (sortField.equals(sortFieldAttribute)) {
            sortAscending = !sortAscending;
        } else {
            sortField = sortFieldAttribute;
            sortAscending = true;
        }

        pageFirst(); // Go to first page and load requested page.
    }

    // Loaders ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void loadDataList() {

        // Load list and totalCount.
        try {
            dataList = list(firstRow, rowsPerPage, sortField, sortAscending);
            totalRows = countDBRowNum(); //count the tablerows
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // Handle it yourself.
        }

        // Set currentPage, totalPages and pages.
        currentPage = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) - ((totalRows - firstRow) / rowsPerPage) + 1;
        totalPages = (totalRows / rowsPerPage) + ((totalRows % rowsPerPage != 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int pagesLength = Math.min(pageRange, totalPages);
        pages = new Integer[pagesLength];

        // firstPage must be greater than 0 and lesser than totalPages-pageLength.
        int firstPage = Math.min(Math.max(0, currentPage - (pageRange / 2)), totalPages - pagesLength);

        // Create pages (page numbers for page links).
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++) {
            pages[i] = ++firstPage;
        }
    }

    // Getters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> getDataList() {
        if (dataList == null) {
            loadDataList(); // Preload page for the 1st view.
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public int getTotalRows() {
        return totalRows;
    }

    public int getFirstRow() {
        return firstRow;
    }

    public int getRowsPerPage() {
        return rowsPerPage;
    }

    public Integer[] getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    // Setters ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage) {
        this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    }

    // Actions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Returns list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index with the given row count,
     * sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     * @param firstRow First index of rows to be returned.
     * @param rowCount Amount of rows to be returned.
     * @param sortField Field to sort the data on.
     * @param sortAscending Whether to sort data ascending or not.
     * @return list of ActiveSessionObj items starting at the given first index with the given row count,
     * sorted by the given sort field and sort order.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public List<ActiveSessionObj> list(int firstRow, int rowCount, String sortField, boolean sortAscending) throws SQLException {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        String sortDirection = sortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

        SqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG WHERE ROWNUM >= ? AND ROWNUM <= ? ORDER BY %s %s";

        String sql = String.format(SqlStatement, sortField, sortDirection);

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<ActiveSessionObj> dataList = new ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj>();

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, firstRow);
                ps.setInt(2, rowCount);

                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
                /* take the result from the SQL query and insert it into Array List collection */
                dataList = ActiveSessionsArrayList(resultSet);

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;

            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }

        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return dataList;
    }

    /**
     * Returns total amount of rows in table.
     * @return Total amount of rows in table.
     * @throws DAOException If something fails at DAO level.
     */
    public int countDBRowNum() throws Exception {

        String SqlStatement = null;

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException();
        }

        SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
            try {
                SqlStatement = "SELECT count(*) FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(SqlStatement);
                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                }

                conn.commit();
                committed = true;
            } finally {
                if (!committed) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }

        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Map the current row of the given ResultSet to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @param resultSet The ResultSet of which the current row is to be mapped to ActiveSessionObj.
     * @return The mapped ActiveSessionObj from the current row of the given ResultSet.
     * @throws SQLException If something fails at database level.
     */
    private static ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> ActiveSessionsArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<ActiveSessionObj> al = null;

        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                al.add(new ActiveSessionObj(
                        rs.getString("ASESSIONID"),
                        rs.getString("USERID"),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYSTART")),
                        timestampToDate(rs.getTimestamp("ACTIVITYEND")),
                        rs.getString("ACTIVITY")));
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

        return al;


        /*
        CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
        ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
        USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
        ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
        ACTIVITY CLOB
        )
         */
    }
    // select all button handle
    private Map<Long, Boolean> selectedIds = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    // get the list from the JSF page
    public Map<Long, Boolean> getSelectedIds() {
        return selectedIds;
    }

    // call this method from the JSF page to delete the selected rows
    public String deleteAction() {

        // do something with the selected rows
        return null;
    }

    private static Date timestampToDate(java.sql.Timestamp ts) {
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new Date(ts.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

When I run the JSF page I don't get any data into the JSF page. I have populated the Oracle table with 3 rows of data. This is not the worse. I get this error stack in Glassfish and the JSF page hangs when I reload the page several times. How this problem can be solved?

Best wishes

**EDIT:** I corrected the code. Now the connection is closed and the page is not hanging but I get this error message when I try open the JSF page. The JSF page still don't show any data from the DB.

```
[#|2012-04-09T16:46:33.241+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=173;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.ActiveSessionsArrayList(Sessions.java:375)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.list(Sessions.java:293)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.loadDataList(Sessions.java:190)
    at com.DX_57.HM_57.Sessions.getDataList(Sessions.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor839.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeEnd(TableRenderer.java:191)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that your connection pool run of connections *"In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections."*

In the posted code you forgot to close the connection in the method `public int count()`.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot find why I cannot display data into the JSF page. Do you see any other errors in the code?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Do you face another Exception now or still the same? You could also (temporarily) increase the number of connections in the pool.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Ok this is another issue, you've a NullPointerException in line 140 you see  javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) so I would guess that you use an uninitialized bean in Expression Language (EL) in one of your JSF pages. You could try to set breakpoints in your JSF to find out which expression causes the issue.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Adding a PhaseListener would also be a good idea if debuggin doesn't work. If nothing works you could comment out half the code to isolate the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure and I haven't tested it but I think there must be @PostConstruct in front of list() methods in order to get the list of data from the data table after the bean is loaded.